# how to select all rows in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms

how to select all rows in DataGridView  on pressing a button ?

i work on C# winforms

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[DataGridView.SelectAll Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectall.aspx)

as easy as calling SelectAll :)

make sure the property `multiselect` is set to true

Answer (score 4):

```
dataGridView.SelectAll()
```

this selects all the DatagridView including the ColumnHeaders . 
But if you want that the ColumnHeaders will not be included

`dataGridView.ColumnHeaders.Visible = false;
 dataGridView.SelectAll();
 dataGridView.ColumnHeaders.Visible = true;`

Please vote :) Thanks a lot...

Comment: need to add semilcolon  and there is no longer ColumnHeaders method, replaced it ColumnHeadersVisible.